# Правильное создание потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Этот код сильно нагружает процессор. Как понимаю, простаевается поток все время.
Пробовал несколько вариантов, но все равно нагрузка не меняется

```
for (;;)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        if (processes[i].ProcessName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("DNSPY"))
            Environment.Exit(0);
    Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Когда процессор выполняет какую-то задачу, он **должен** нагружаться. Это естественно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тут дело не в том что нагрузки не должно быть, тут проблема в бесконечном цикле который перегружает процессор на 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task.Delay работает только в асинхронной функции, при условии, что его дожидаются через await. Если у Вас отдельный Thread для этой задачи, то можно использовать Thread.Sleep(100);
пример:

```
private async Task DoSomeWorkAsync() 
{
   for (;;)
   {
       Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
       for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
          if (processes[i].ProcessName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("DNSPY"))
              Environment.Exit(0);
       await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Либо:

```
private void DoSomeWork() 
{
    new Thread(() => {
      for (;;)
      {
         Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
         for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
            if (processes[i].ProcessName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("DNSPY"))
                Environment.Exit(0);
         Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
    }).Start();
}
```

Вариант с Task предпочтительней.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, нагрузка упала до 0.1% :)